# KFold unpacks the number of splits into the same number of variables, instead of just 2

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-fold

I am using a simple KFold split:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=123)

train_idx, val_idx = kfold.split(X_train)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I noticed that if the number of `n_splits` matches the number variables to unpack to, it works fine. So it unpacks each split of train & test into a separate variable.

However,  the user guide states that it yields only 2 variables.

I would like to unpack all the splits into 2 variables: 1 for all the train indices split, and 1 for all the test indices split.

Answer (score 0):

KFold returns a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) :

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
import numpy as np
X = np.random.normal(0,1,(10,5))
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=123)
type(kfold.split(X_train))

generator
```

It is meant for use in for loops, and you can what it will iterate through, for example on the first iteration:

```
list(kfold.split(X_train))[0]

(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35,
        36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55,
        56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 69, 70, 71, 74]),
 array([23, 24, 42, 43, 45, 68, 72, 73]))
```

So what you have above only works when you have n_splits=2, because the data structure is that of a single element.

If you really want collect all the indices, then I think this is one way:

```
train_idx = []
val_idx = []
for x,y in kfold.split(X_train):
    train_idx.append(x)
    val_idx.append(y)
```